# 2 lenses came with my Nikon D3200, but no adapter. What do I need to buy to use these lenses?

Tags: adapter

When I purchased my Nikon D3200, 2 off brand lenses came with it. One is a 2 x telephoto lens/52 mm thread, the other is a .45 x wide angle(macro) lens/52 mm thread, both are digital lenses.
The lenses do not screw onto my camera. What do I need to buy to be able to use the lenses? Are they worth using, or should I just buy the equivalent Nikor lenses? Thanks

Comment: We need more information on the exact make and models of these lenses to be able to help you, they may not be of any use at all.

Comment: It might also be easier to provide photos (of at least front/back of the lenses), maybe through imgur or other photo upload sites, instead of trying to provide a detailed description.

Answer (score 7):

Those lenses sound like auxiliary "converter" lenses, which are generally intended to thread onto the filter threads of another lens to convert that lens to a longer or wider focal length. They're more common for advanced point-and-shoot cameras than SLRs and won't do anything useful without a lens to mount them onto.

In my experience, these converter lenses are nearly useless attached to SLR lenses. The image quality is quite poor.

If you're looking for advice on lenses, I'd recommend a Nikon 18-55 VR and/or a Nikon 35mm f/1.8 lens to start with. The 18-55 will give you a very useful zoom range and image stabilization, while the 35mm will give you excellent low-light ability at the expense of zooming. Once you've had experience with either of those, it will be more clear to you which other lenses you might want to acquire to expand your system.

Comment: I have 3 lenses for the Nikon, 18-55, 55-200 & 70-300, all Nikor lenses. They all give excellent zoom & very clear pictures. Since I am fairly new to digital photography and quite a dummy I might add, was thinking these other two lenses described above would need to be screwed directly to the camera. However, they screw onto the front of the 18-55 & the 55-200, voila! Was looking more to use the wide angle lens & will have to try it to see if the pics are any good. Helpful comment, thanks

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like they're actually adaptors/filters for lenses, rather than lenses in their own right.

The 52mm thread can be screwed onto the front of a variety of lenses, like the standard 18-55mm kit lens. The 2x telephoto adaptor will make the lens "longer", or more telephoto (it will magnify objects more), while the 0.45x wide angle adaptor will make things smaller, and give you a wider field of view.

In short, you need a regular lens for the camera (and if you get one with a 52mm thread, those two adaptors will be potentially quite useful)

Comment: From your comment I figured out that these lenses screw to the front of my Nikor 18-55 & 55-200. Still have a lot to learn, will experiment with said lenses to see what happens. Very useful comment, thanks.